# Calling onClick (to setAttribute) inside Array.map() Throws an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am building a Gutenberg Block in Wordpress that uses react and what I am trying to achive is that when a div is clicked it should setAttributes with subpage id. the array.map() is used to create each dive with dynamic value that has to be clicked.

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks; // Import registerBlockType() from wp.blocks
const { RichText } = wp.editor;
const { withSelect } = wp.data;

const { Fragment, Component  } = wp.element;
const {InspectorControls, PanelColorSettings, BlockControls, BlockAlignmentToolbar,MediaUpload } = wp.editor;
const {
    RangeControl,
    SelectControl,
    TextControl,
    ToggleControl,
    Dashicon,
    IconButton,
    Button,
    Toolbar,
    PanelBody,
    RadioControl,
    TabPanel,
} = wp.components

const {
          attributes,
          setAttributes,
        } = this.props;
        const {
          subpagesArray,
          indexArray,
          align,
          currentSelected,
          displayPageExcerpt,
          displayPageIcon,
          displayPageTitle
        } = attributes;

     <section className="gosign-content-nav-block">
        {subpagesArray.map(subpage => {
            return (
                  <div className="subpage-block" onClick ={() => {setAttributes({currentSelected : subpage.id});}}  >
                       {displayPageIcon &&
                        <div className="subpage-icon">
                          <span className="accessibility">
                            <i className="material-icons">accessibility</i>
                          </span>

                         </div>
                        }
                        {displayPageTitle &&
                         <div className="subpage-title">
                            <p>{subpage.title.rendered}</p>
                         </div>
                        }
                  </div>
                )
            })}
      </section>
```

In my opinion this is some 'this' reffrence issue. It would be great if I can get a quick help.

Comment: Can you show the `setAttributes` code (where toLowerCase is invoked). I think changing to `subpage.id || ""` should work?

Comment: setAttribute is the default function for gutenberg and toLowerCase is not being called any where in code. As far as I have googles it seems like reffernce issue.

Comment: @ridamukhtar as mentioned above, please provide the setAttributes method, gutenberg "default function" is just a function used by the plugin, if you open the source and some point he will make tolowercase trim etc.

Comment: @ConstantinTrepadus in console all the files are minified:
react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0:103 TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at block-editor.min.js?ver=3.2.4:49
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)

Comment: @ridamukhtar if you cant reach the source, can you log your both currentSelected and subpage objects ? one of them is null

Comment: @ConstantinTrepadus i have log and checked and no one is null they have values

Comment: We need more code. or full error log. Make sure to set `define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );` in your `wp-config.php` to get the error log that is more comprehandable.